# $q.all(promises)and structure of promises object to collect the returned data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I am using Angularjs `$q.all(promises)` to make multiple REST call and then collecting the data once promise is successful. I have following following.

1. If "promises is simple array then it works  [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AYV37a?p=preview)

   ```
   var promises = [
      Users.query().$promise,
      Repositories.query().$promise
   ];
   ```
2. If "promises" is simple object then also it works [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sn52H7?p=preview)

   ```
   var promises = {
      users: Users.query().$promise,
      repos: Repositories.query().$promise
   };
   ```
3. If "promises" is nested object then it is not working. For my requirement I need nested object to remember the input parameters.  [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HhkR1U?p=preview)

   ```
   var promises = {
      users: {"phx":Users.query().$promise},
      repos: {"phx":Repositories.query().$promise}
   };
   ```

These plunkr are just to simulate my problem. However I want this approach in real project for following requirement.

> 1. I have list of 12 product
> 2. Each product has "details", "benefits" and "offers" data
> 3. I have separate REST API services for "details", "benefits" and "offers" having :productID as parameter
> 4. I am making call in following order
>
>    a. Loop for each cards
>
>    b. For each card, make a REST API call for "details", "benefits" and "offers"
>
>    c. Add #b steps into "promises" object
>
>    d. call
>
>    ```
>    $q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
>        // Here need logic to compile the result back to product 
>        // and corresponding  "details", "benefits" and "offers" mapping
>      }
>    ```
>
>    and get the data back

Following is json structure I needed to collect my response.

```
{
    "prod1": {
      "benefits": {},
      "offers": {},
      "pages": {
        "productPage": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "common": {
    "benefits": {},
    "pages": {
      "commonBenefit": {}
    },
    "others": {}
  }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `$q.all` works with either an array or an object. It does not work with nested array, since it won't deep-look for promises to resolve them. You will have to explain more details *why* you need a nested array and we'll suggest an alternative approach

Comment: It looks like all you are trying to do is prepend the key name phx...

Comment: "phx" is just an example to get the result back as desired structure. I want to maintain the required input.

Comment: @DilipKumar, insted of describing the data structure in words, show what it is and where you want to populate it with the data. I'm still not clear on what you want

Comment: I have added my sample json structure that I needed to collect the response. I tried the approach shred by "c4605" and it worked. Thanks for your help to explain the basics as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need it, you can wrap the nest with `$q.all` like this:

```
var promises = {
  users: $q.all({"phx": Users.query().$promise}),
  repos: $q.all({"phx": Repositories.query().$promise})
};
```

[plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/s825H6hkLzUqxHrFMpLU?p=preview)